# How to get alpha names for my program?

Tags: minecraft

When you see games in BETA and ALPHA, lets use Minecraft as example, Minecraft when it was in ALPHA the title for the ALPHA versions for Minecraft where like "Minecraft APLHA C1.2.2_C1.2" for example. Not that it's really important but how do they get the numbers and letters (C1.2.2_C1.2 <- these numbers and letters) and what do they represent for is it numbers that are just kinda random? and how does a person go about to getting those numbers for there program? I normally just go ALPHA 1 - how many updates there is but I find it more professional to have titles like this "Minecraft APLHA C1.2.2_C1.2"? Thanks

Comment: You might find this useful: http://semver.org

Comment: You can name it what you want. If you think it's more professional to have more complex versions, invent one. How about *ALPHA_6.2x_Phase3_SubVersion23.22.412-X.73*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly uninformed answer is this:

Every development department of every software company in the world has their own versioning system, and the numbers and codes that follow a program name (when included at all) simply reflect whatever system happens to be in use. Different code repositories have different standards as well. It might be something like this:

myProgram-5.2.3.4

The 5 being first in the list, might mean this is the fifth major revision of this application. A major revision would be when the program has been fundamentally changed, like when a programming language that has never had OOP support suddenly caves in and provides it to their user base.

The 2, being second, would be a big change to the application that does not fundamentally alter it, maybe like a shoot'em up game implementing several new weapons that people had been begging for but didn't really change anything else about game play.

Successive digits indicate less important changes, with the last digit often representing bug-fixes - changes that are typically invisible to the end user but make the program more robust.

There are many other systems; it's up to you to decide which to use. I would do some searching on topics like "version control best practices" to learn more. Once you know what those numbers mean, you may find they tell you important details about an application you were unaware of.